# Json to java objects error

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse the response from an external webservice into java objects and receiving an error. 
The error I am getting is :

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unrecognized field "TransactionDetail" (Class
>   com.services.restAuthorization.AuthorizationResponse), not marked
>   as ignorable  at [Source: weblogic.net.http.KeepAliveStream@1962957;
>   line: 2, column: 27] (through reference chain:
>   com.dnb.services.restAuthorization.AuthorizationResponse["TransactionDetail"]);
>   nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "TransactionDetail" (Class
>   com.services.restAuthorization.AuthorizationResponse), not marked
>   as ignorable

Here is the java code to connect and parse the response.

```
ResponseEntity<AuthorizationResponse> auth = template.exchange("https://XXXX", HttpMethod.POST, entity, AuthorizationResponse.class);

If instead of ResponseEntity<AuthorizationResponse> I get the response as ResponseEntity<String>, I get this response : 


<200 OK,{
"TransactionDetail": {
    "ServiceTransactionID": "Id-e1f7d45992063d008e976500ed7f5c9c",
    "TransactionTimestamp": "2017-10-04T11:01:53.588",
    "ApplicationTransactionID":""
},
"TransactionResult": {
    "SeverityText": "Information",
    "ResultID": "CM000",
    "ResultText":  "Success",
    "ResultMessage": {
     "ResultDescription":  "Success"
    }
},
"AuthenticationDetail": {
    "Token": "AqcI6qpJ0A8uOu6BvGP0rZ"
}
},{Date=[Wed, 04 Oct 2017 15:01:53 GMT], Server=[], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive], X-CorrelationID=[Id-e1f7d45992063d008e976500ed7f5c9c 0], Accept=[text/plain, application/json, */*], Accept-Charset=[big5, big5-hkscs, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai, ibm00858, ibm01140, ibm01141, ibm01142, ibm01143, ibm01144, ibm01145, ibm01146, ibm01147, ibm01148, ibm01149, ibm037, ibm1026, ibm1047, ibm273, ibm277, ibm278, ibm280, ibm284, ibm285, ibm297, ibm420, ibm424, ibm437, ibm500, ibm775, ibm850, ibm852, ibm855, ibm857, ibm860, ibm861, ibm862, ibm863, ibm864, ibm865, ibm866, ibm868, ibm869, ibm870, ibm871, ibm918, iso-2022-cn, iso-2022-jp, iso-2022-jp-2, iso-2022-kr, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-13, iso-8859-15, iso-8859-2, iso-8859-3, iso-8859-4, iso-8859-5, iso-8859-6, iso-8859-7, iso-8859-8, iso-8859-9, jis_x0201, jis_x0212-1990, koi8-r, koi8-u, shift_jis, tis-620, us-ascii, utf-16, utf-16be, utf-16le, utf-32, utf-32be, utf-32le, utf-8, windows-1250, windows-1251, windows-1252, windows-1253, windows-1254, windows-1255, windows-1256, windows-1257, windows-1258, windows-31j, x-big5-solaris, x-euc-jp-linux, x-euc-tw, x-eucjp-open, x-ibm1006, x-ibm1025, x-ibm1046, x-ibm1097, x-ibm1098, x-ibm1112, x-ibm1122, x-ibm1123, x-ibm1124, x-ibm1381, x-ibm1383, x-ibm33722, x-ibm737, x-ibm833, x-ibm834, x-ibm856, x-ibm874, x-ibm875, x-ibm921, x-ibm922, x-ibm930, x-ibm933, x-ibm935, x-ibm937, x-ibm939, x-ibm942, x-ibm942c, x-ibm943, x-ibm943c, x-ibm948, x-ibm949, x-ibm949c, x-ibm950, x-ibm964, x-ibm970, x-iscii91, x-iso-2022-cn-cns, x-iso-2022-cn-gb, x-iso-8859-11, x-jis0208, x-jisautodetect, x-johab, x-macarabic, x-maccentraleurope, x-maccroatian, x-maccyrillic, x-macdingbat, x-macgreek, x-machebrew, x-maciceland, x-macroman, x-macromania, x-macsymbol, x-macthai, x-macturkish, x-macukraine, x-ms932_0213, x-ms950-hkscs, x-mswin-936, x-pck, x-sjis_0213, x-utf-16le-bom, x-utf-32be-bom, x-utf-32le-bom, x-windows-50220, x-windows-50221, x-windows-874, x-windows-949, x-windows-950, x-windows-iso2022jp], Authorization=[AqclWQMDSMSIJJ48D42ymOgvAjyNAQZWWIzyxGPpPmdYxJqbdhyNlUOYI6qpJ0A8uOu6BvGP0rZ], Host=[direct.dnb.com], User-Agent=[Java1.6.0_24], X-Forwarded-For=[152.120.124.110], Content-Type=[application/json], Vary=[Accept-Encoding]}>
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out why I am getting this error? Here is my AuthorizationResponse.class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"TransactionDetail",
"TransactionResult",
"AuthenticationDetail"
})

public class AuthorizationResponse {

@JsonProperty("TransactionDetail")
private TransactionDetail transactionDetail;
@JsonProperty("TransactionResult")
private TransactionResult transactionResult;
@JsonProperty("AuthenticationDetail")
private AuthenticationDetail authenticationDetail;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
....GETTERS SETTERS, ETC.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I resolved it. Here is the answer in case it helps someone else.

I reverted back to using  ResponseEntity and used an object mapper to convert to AuthorizationResponse java object.

```
ResponseEntity<String> auth = template.exchange("https://XXXX", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AuthorizationResponse resp = new AuthorizationResponse();
    resp = mapper.readValue(auth.getBody(), new TypeReference<AuthorizationResponse>(){});
```